# Laravel 5.5 Socialite Error

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I have an issue with Socialite on Laravel 5.5 I have Socialite required by composer, updated services.php with different providers credential and updated providers in app.php This is the error I am getting

Type error: Argument 1 passed to Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteManager::formatRedirectUrl() must be of the type array, null given

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In most of the cases, the issue is solved through 3 steps:

1. Run `php artisan clear-compiled`
2. Run `composer dump-autoload`
3. Run `php artisan optimize`

Hope it helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check `config/services.php` for the provider you're authenticating with. The redirect entry needs to be set to your defined route.

```
'redirect' => 'http://your-callback-url'
```

Example:

```
// config.services.php
'github' => [
    'client_id' => env('GITHUB_CLIENT_ID'),   
    'client_secret' => env('GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    'redirect' => 'http://example.com/github/redirect',
],

// routes/web.php
Route::get('github/redirect', 'GitHubController@redirect')
```